# Routing in Symfony2 with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony

I have Symfony2 for REST api and AngularJS on the front-end. Can't figure out how to deal with the routing. I have the following setup, that doesn't work:

In the Symfony2 controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @Route("/post/{slug}", name="post")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    // index.html.twig is a plain html file with inclusion of all the scripts
    return $this->render('AcmeAppBundle::index.html.twig');
}
```

Angular setup:

```
angular.module('acmeApp', [])
    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/assets/partials/index.html',
                    controller: "MainCtrl"
                })
                .when('/post/:slug', {
                    templateUrl: '/assets/partials/post.html',
                    controller: "PostCtrl"
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }
    ])
    .config(['$locationProvider',
        function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        }
    ])
```

When I open `acme.com/` and follow a link to `acme.com/post/123`, this works fine, Angular picks up the route. But when I start from `acme.com/post/123`, Symfony2 redirect to `acme.com/post`and I'm not getting to the post page.

Any recommendation how you setup routing in Symfony2 to use with Angular JS?

**Update:**
Adding `<base href="/">` to `index.html.twig` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Routes in `Symfony` are not the same as routes in `AngularJS`. E.g. `http://example.org/post/123#!/` would be `/post/123` on Symfony but `/` on Angular.

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli make sense. Any idea how to approach routing then?

Comment: As long as `/post/123` is returning a JSON representation of a *post* with id 123, and `/post` an array of posts, you can create an Angular app that uses `$resource` to load the list of posts and post detail, see here for more details: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: Have a look also here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location and here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli but isn't Symfony going to intercept the route `/post/123` and Angular interpret it as `/`?

Comment: The two things are unrelated, you use routes on Angular to dynamically load HTML fragments on the client-side. My suggestions: start with a simple Angular app, don't use Angular routes in the beginning, until you get acquainted :-)

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli thanks! I've played with Angular routes, they've worked well, until I incorporate them with Symfony. Symfony has it's own high level routing. In my case, adding `<base href="/">` to `index.html.twig` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: all right, good luck!